# LibSpotify and Windows Store App

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, spotify

I'd like to start work on a Windows Store App client for Spotify, using LibSpotify. However, it seems that I'm unable to use the libspotify dll from inside a Metro app, presumably because it uses parts of the win32 api that are off-limits to the Metro Sandbox.

Loading in my own simple test dll using LoadPackagedLibrary works ok, but loading in libspotify gives error 1114 - ERROR_DLL_INIT_FAILED.

Is there any hope for me?

Thanks
Tom

Comment: I think you can create a windows service (a daemon) that runs in the background and communicates with your WinRT app. The service can use the DLL. I don't know how to actually implement this however.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to create a Metro-Style-App - you have no hope until Spotify releases an updated library or someone reverse engineers their library to make it work in WinRT.

If you want to create a Metro style app that is not WinRT - based - there are WPF libraries that let you theme your application to look Metro, but you won't be able to sell it in Windows Store unless you work for Spotify and get into a deal with Microsoft.

Comment: But are we sure it's the case that the spotfiy dll uses 'blacklisted' parts of win32?

Comment: Sorry, I just assumed that was the case reading your question.

Comment: I assume it is the case as well, but I'm not sure if there is a good way to find out whether and arbitrary dll will work under Metro.

In the meantime, I suppose I could proceed by creating a xaml based desktop app in the style of a Metro one, and then porting this to Metro when/if the spotify api becomes compatible.

Comment: Perhaps the app certification test would help.

Comment: As far as I can tell,that is the only way to be sure, yes. I need to first figure out why the dll won't load. However, given that the spotify dll will be (amongst other things) trying to maintain a large file cache on the computer's disk, I can't see that it would pass!

Comment: I can't run it because I can't get the dll to load into the Metro App!

Comment: Sorry, I don't have much experience with the certification kit, but I thought it gives some details without having to run the app. I guess I was wrong.

Answer (score -2):

You can only use the WinRT library in Windows 8 Metro Apps, not Win32.

Comment: You can use regular libraries as long as they only use whitelisted APIs.